# ResultSet#isFirst() does not indicate that a row exists

Tags: java, ms-access, select, jdbc, ucanaccess

I just faced with a problem in getting data from ms access in java program i'm using ucanaccess driver following is my code

```
public void loginUser(){
  // variables
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    // Step 1: Loading or 
    // registering Oracle JDBC driver class
    try {

        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfex) {

        System.out.println("Problem in loading or "
                + "registering MS Access JDBC driver");
        cnfex.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Step 2: Opening database connection
    try {

        String msAccDB; 
                msAccDB = "C:/Users/Hidayat Ullah/Documents/Record.accdb";
        String dbURL = "jdbc:ucanaccess://"
                + msAccDB; 

        // Step 2.A: Create and 
        // get connection using DriverManager class
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL); 

        // Step 2.B: Creating JDBC Statement 
  String  sql= "SELECT * FROM Student WHERE studentid = ? AND password = ?";
 PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
  //printing here loginId.getText() and loginPass.getText() always has value 
  //i entered in the gui
 pstmt.setString(1, loginId.getText()); 
 pstmt.setString(2,loginPass.getText());
 ResultSet row = pstmt.executeQuery();

if(row.isFirst()){
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Student ID 
:"+row.getString("studentid"));
 System.exit(0);
  }else{
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No such record exists in database 
 against this ID, either ID or Password is incorrect.");
 System.exit(0);
 }
```

the problem is that when i entered the user id and password that is in the db but it always return no record. what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

When a `ResultSet` object is initially created it is positioned *before* the first row, so `.isFirst()` will return `false` until you call `.next()` to position the `ResultSet` *on* the first row (if one exists). Instead of calling `.isFirst()` your code can simply call `.next()` and if it returns `true` then at least one matching row was found.